# Find a particular menu item within the primary links

Tags: 6, routes

Let's say we have a menu inside the primary links, in my case the Misc menu.

[image: menu_tree_primary_links]

As it seems under Misc menu it can be any Content Type (of course and on every other menu)

The question is how can I make it to appear ONLY the Misc menu somewhere in my website without reconstructing it as a separate menu?

I want it to stay in the primary links.

So far I've tried it with the context module, but seems that is not working properly with the sub menus under the Misc menu. It works only for the Misc page.

Even if I do this: [menu_set_active_menu_name](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_set_active_menu_name/6) ('primary-links') it's still working only for the Misc menu, not its childrens.

Creating a block with only the needed menu item and the use of the [template_preprocess_block](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_block/6) is another approach but not recommended, while I have to refer to the block through the block ID (`$bid`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Menu block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block) - it provides configurable blocks of menu trees starting with any level of any menu. 
So if you’re only using your theme’s Main menu links feature, you can add and configure a “Main menu (levels 2+)” block. That block would appear once you were on one of the Main menu’s pages and would show the menu tree for the 2nd level (and deeper) of your Main menu and would expand as you traversed down the tree. You can also limit the depth of the menu’s tree (e.g. “Main menu (levels 2-3)”) and/or expand all the child sub-menus (e.g. “Main menu (expanded levels 2+)”).

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response, this is worked perfect!  


--------- 

But , what if I wanted to add a body_class to all of the links under the Misc menu (to all its childs, without clicking one by one, but to be them considered that they are in active trail or something like that) , I mean when I editing my context Conditions and choose Misc menu I want for every child to inherit this body_class. Of course in my context Reactions I appear my Misc menu block with the defined body_class.

Comment: You should add to your template.php template_page_preprocess function, and add there body classes dependly what shown at current moment.

Comment: You are so right, but what about the block, template_preprocess_block() maybe?
I mean, I want it appearing under those pages also

Comment: I am not sure what you mean...

Comment: bad wording.
When I click on a link under the Misc menu I want only the Misc block from the primary-links to appear.
I can't define this throw the block visibility settings because the url does not follow any standard pattern e.g node/%  it can be anything e.g. page/%, news/% etc

Comment: So then you visit Misc menu item via Primary menu, you want to show Misc menu block?

Comment: Exactly! I 've tried this through contexts but it works only for the Misc menu item, not its children

Comment: Well, in this case you should write block visibility code, there you should find menu item by path, then check is this menu belong to 'Misc' menu tree.